# How to authenticate at Microsoft Report Server 2008 using Android SDK (Java)?

Tags: java, android, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ntlm

I am currently trying to create an app that needs to access a single file on a MS Reportserver 2008 using a network connection. Normally, I do this kind of things by using the `Authenticator.getPasswordAuthentication` class to authenticate a user, and then getting the file using the HttpURLConnection class. On other servers, this usually works, but obviously ReportServer needs some other kind of authentication, because I always get an error 401 (`java.io.IOException: No authentication challenges found`).

I just wonder: what is the desired way to generally access a single file on a MS Report Server? How can I authenticate a user, and then get access to a file? I have no clue how to correctly authenticate to that Microsoft system using Android SDK, preferably without the requirement of using a third-party lib.

Do you have any suggestion how to easily handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Reporting Services can be tapped into .You can get A list of reports and/or folders and/or metadata by connection.